# The dimension of a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

This is part of a step for a larger problem that I am working on, but I just wanted to make sure that I said this part correctly.

I have the set of points $\{(x,x-y,y,z,0): x,y,z \in \mathcal{R}\}$ and I want to make sure that I say precisely that the dimension of this vector space is $3$. I know this because only 3 of the coordinates can be varied independently, so the dimension must be $3$.

Would a good way to say this be to somehow use the replacement theorem? For example, I can throw out the $0$ coordinate since it is linearly dependent on the other coordinates. This will not change the span. Then I can throw out the $x-y$ coordinate since it is a linear combination of the first and third, this also will not change the span. So then I would have the points $(x,y,z)$ and each of these coordinates can be varied independantly, so they are not linear combinations of eachother, and they still span the space. Since this is a basis the dimension of the space must be $3$.

I guess I'm just having trouble relating the point notation to the linear combination of vectors notation.

Could somebody point out if I'm doing this wrong, or if it is correct help me refine the language?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That set of points is described as the row space of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The dimension of the row space is at least 3, since the middle 3x3 submatrix has determinant 1:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since there are only 3 rows, it follows that the row space has dimension precisely 3.